# Swagger - How to write common response field?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have several APIs, and all of them return JSON with a boolean field named `success`.

API 1
`{"success": true, "data": "some data"}`

API 2
`{"success": false, "error": "error message"}`

Can I write its swagger 2.0 document with something like a template, so I don't need to copy and paste the success field part in each API like this?

```
  responses:
    200:
      schema:
        properties:
          success:
            type: boolean
             description: true if the request is successful.
          data:
             ...
```

and

```
  responses:
    200:
      schema:
        properties:
          success:
            type: boolean
             description: true if the request is successful.
          error:
             ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use `allOf` for the common fields:

```
responses:
  200:
    schema:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/common'
        - properties:
            data:
            # your details here

definitions:
  Common:
    type: object
    properties:
      success:
        type: boolean
         description: true if the request is successful.
```

Also:

```
      schema:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Common'
          - properties:
              data:
                $ref: '#/definitions/Another'
```